# get JSON from another site and turn into array or csv

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, go

I'm trying to turn the value at the key of "1" of this cross-domain JSON into a js array on my site.

I tried using `$.getJSON()`, but I encountered a cross-domain origin error. I tried AJAX and got a cross-domain origin error.

Is there any way I can get around this and user the JSON?

Here is my attempt using `$.getJSON()`:

```
var trends = '';
var json = 'http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/';
$.getJSON(json, function(trends){
    console.log(trends["1"]);
});
```

Here is my AJAX attempt:

```
    $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    data:{},
    url:'http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/',
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(jqXHR);
    },
    success:function(msg){
        if (msg) {
          var myArray = [];
          $.each(msg, function(i, item) {
             //do whatever you want for each row in json
             myArray.push(item);
          });
        }
    }
});
```

If the only way to do this is on a server. How can I parse the JSON and turn the values of the key "1" to elements in a CSV file in Go ( Golang ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like:

```
var json = 'http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/';
$.getJSON(json, function(trends){
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:json,
    dataType:'JSONP',
    data: trends,
    success: function(msg){
      // do stuff with the msg
    }
  });
});
```

Since `trends` returns the data from `$.getJSON` you run your AJAX later. There is really no reason to do this, if you have server access.

Using PHP:

```
<?php
$dataArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/'));
// $dataArray has all data
?>
```

Comment: there is an array at trends["1"]. Go to the site where the jSON is and  find `"1"` in the page. There is an array there: `"1": ["Slender Man", "Rihanna", "George Jung", "Mortal Kombat X", "Scout Willis", "iOS 8", "Blackhawks", "Game of Thrones", "WWE", "Chris Brown", "Lauren Scruggs", "Gwendoline Christie", "AAPL", "Jean Kasem", "Spurs", "Ann B Davis", "earthquake", "Lewis Katz", "Luis Montes", "OTF Nunu"]`

Comment: but then how can I access that php variable in js?

Comment: You could use `$.ajax({})`, send data to the server where that information is already available from my above PHP example. You `echo json_encode($dataArray);` on your PHP page, which will return upon `success` of the said AJAX query, passing the result to the Anonymous function assigned to the `success` property.

Comment: Make sure you run regular expressions on your server side, if you are sending data using AJAX that goes into your database, as the data can be altered by the client.