# read online JSON and save values to CSV in Golang

Tags: json, csv, go

I'm am currently able to decode in-programme JSON.

However, I want to decode online JSON and save some values as values in a CSV file.

Here is my current code: http://play.golang.org/p/tVz4cEaL-R

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"


type Response struct {
    Region string `json:"1"`
    Trends []string `json:"2"`
}



func main() {

    str := `{"1": ["apple", "banana"], "2": ["apple", "peach"]}`
    res := &Response{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &res)
    fmt.Println(res.Trends)
}
```

The JSON I'm trying to process instead of the current-value of `str` is here: http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/

`res.Trends` are the values that I want and I want to take each of them and write them to a .csv

Comment: possible duplicate of [get JSON from another site and turn into array or csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026056/get-json-from-another-site-and-turn-into-array-or-csv)

Comment: Not a duplicate as that link you provided is for jQuery in JavaScript. This question here is for GoLang - a totally different language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That JSON is malformed, it should return an array not an object, however you can use a map to achieve what you want : [`play`](http://play.golang.org/p/XiWWR_9sgy)

```
func main() {

    str := `{"1": ["apple", "banana"], "2": ["apple", "peach"]}`
    res := map[string][]string{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &res)
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Update [`play`](http://play.golang.org/p/5hKhLM9pzv) :

```
func get_json(url string) []byte {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return body
}

func main() {

    res := map[string][]string{}
    json.Unmarshal(get_json("http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/"), &res)
    for k, v := range res {
        fmt.Printf("%s=%#v\n", k, v)
    }
}
```

I really recommend you go through the documentation, it's very straight forward.

Check :

1. http://tour.golang.org/#1
2. http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

Comment: Thank you. However, now, how can I parse the JSON from that site as that changes at least every day and I want it to be current every time the programme runs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse first in the format that @OneOfOne suggested and then put it inside your structure:

http://play.golang.org/p/A9TQ1d1Glt

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

var data = `{...}`

type Response struct {
    Region int
    Trends []string
}

func main() {
    res := map[string][]string{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &res)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    }
    responses := make([]Response, len(res))
    i := 0
    for id, values := range res {
        id_int, err := strconv.Atoi(id)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error for id:", id)
            continue
        }
        responses[i].Region = id_int
        responses[i].Trends = values
        i += 1
    }

    for i:=0; i < len(responses); i += 1{
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", responses[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, how can I parse from the online file? As the online JSON will change daily. So I would like to get the json each time this programme runs and then parse it.